# How can I rename a lot of files with bash using a regex?

Tags: bash

I want to rename a lot of files with bash scripting:

Original:

```
Kassai_szemle_1885_00015.jpg 
Kassai_szemle_1885_00016.jpg 
Kassai_szemle_1885_00017.jpg
```

It should renamed to:

```
Kassai_Szemle_1885_00015.jpg 
Kassai_Szemle_1885_00016.jpg 
Kassai_Szemle_1885_00017.jpg
```

Only the "s" should be renamed to uppercase "S".

How can i do it with bash?

Comment: Do all the files start with that prefix, or is this supposed to turn any lower-case name into Title Case?

Comment: Yes, all the files start with the prefix "Kassai_" .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use a Substitution Expansion

You don't really need a regular expression here, although you could use one with the non-standard `rename` command or by parsing filenames with sed, awk, or perl. However, you can also just use Bash's built-in [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to handle this easily. For example:

```
for file in *_szemle_*
do
    mv "$file" "${file/_szemle/_Szemle}"
done
```

Comment: @Lennier `>` is your *$PS2* character. You are either missing a newline somewhere, copied or pasted something incorrectly, or are doing something else wrong that is causing Bash to wait for you to complete an expression. The code works fine.

Answer (score 6):

There is a `rename` utility available under GNU/Linux (Like Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat... while standard `perl` is normaly installed), which makes it easy.

You can run it in the folder with all those mentioned files like:

```
rename 's/^Kassai_s/Kassai_S/' Kassai_s*.jpg
```